# JViewerPane inside a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a JEditorPane that I need to attach a scrollbar to. I am attempting to nest the JEditorPane inside a JScrollPane. Here I provide an SSCCE.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        //Generate filler text to illustrate the lack of a scrollbar
        String fillerText = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
            fillerText += "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. ";
        }

        //Initialize JEditorPane
        JEditorPane viewer = new JEditorPane();
        viewer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
        viewer.setText(fillerText);

        //Initialize JScrollPane
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(viewer);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        //Add viewer to the frame
        frame.add(viewer);

        //Make frame visible
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Why is no scrollbar made visible, and how can I make one visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in next: you add `JEditorPane` to your `JFrame` instead of `JScrollPane`. When you need to use `JScrollPane` you add component to that view and add `JScrollPane` to container.

Replace `frame.add(viewer);` with `frame.add(scroll);` and it will be work.

Comment: Works perfectly. I suppose I must have misunderstood the tutorial I was reading. Thanks.